# Using the logo as the About button

Tags: buttons, layout, interface

This is obviously something that the user doesn't need to see very often, but something that management or sales might have strong opinions about.

In a desktop application the user is probably going to go to once or twice (maybe to check version number or licence information), is it a good idea to integrate this button into the logo (since it is difficult to tell whether it is a place to click)? I have seen increasing use of this in the modern software applications, so I am wondering if it is a common practice and what the rationale is compared to just creating a distinct help or about button.

Comment: I would think very carefully about how well established the web idiom 'logo click goes home' is

Answer (score 2):

### **Only do it as a secondary option**

I would say you need to to have a clear path to the "about" section or whatever it may be.

If you were to connect it to a logo, I would probably only do it as a secondary way to get to the about section.

All that said, I don't think it is uncommon for a logo in a desktop application to offer information about the application. However, on websites, logos typically link to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think twice before considering anything common knowledge, and then think about it some more if it's about a feature that might be very useful.

Either stick the logo in a button shape, or add some form of indication that it's a link.

And then still it might seem like a "home" button, depending on where you show it.

Comment: In a desktop application situation, there isn't really a concept of home if most of the actions take place in a main application window. How would this change your answer?

Comment: It would put more emphasis on making it seem like an element that allows for interaction. I think @DesignerGuy worded it quite nicely; make it a secondary option. Put a button somewhere that does exactly the same thing, because nobody is going t know what the logo does until they click it - *if* they click it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the product. Is the about section something your users need to find by themselves?

Version numbers are useful for cc/support/developers and **sometimes** users.

If your users don't need to find the about section, then it's OK since your support/developers will know where to find it. However, it might become a hassle when something goes wrong and you need to instruct users by email/phone each and every time, to click the logo in order to get the version number so you can debug their problems. *(If you give support over something like TeamViewer that's not such a big problem)*

In most cases users won't care much about version numbers until something goes wrong, so hiding the about section is often a good thing. However, the logotype should probably not be considered the common place for an about section. Hide it in a menu item instead.